Automated transmission system clutch engagement
Can someone explain on which factors the clutch engagement and also disengagement depend in AMT? And how to understand the synchronization of speeds of Input shaft, Main shaft, Layshaft, and outshaft?
As the synchronization is also important for clutch.

matching engine speed to transmission and road speed is part of the process then the synchro units help the rest - covers those bad drivers that can't drive a "crash" box...

It depends on the brake and gas pedals also.
